# How to optimize vector operations on arrays in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing a mechanism for a wallpaper gallery that would allow to search for visually similar images. Each wallpaper in the database have a "simdata" property that is an array of normalized pixels. My idea is to compute visual similarity between two wallpapers by calculating mean deviation between corresponding elements of their "simdata" vectors. Here's the solution in Postgres I came up with:

```sql
select "w".*, (
    select 100 - 100 * avg(abs(simdata[i] - ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])[i])) / 255
        from (
            select generate_subscripts('{1,2,3}'::integer[], 1) as i
        ) as "t"
) as "similarity"
from "wallpapers" as "w"
order by "similarity" desc
limit 24
```

Where '{1,2,3}' is just a placeholder for a huge array of 1024 elements. It works, but doesn't look like a good solution in terms performance. Is it possible to improve it?

UPD. Came up with a slightly better query:

```sql
select "w".id, (
    select 100 - 100 * avg(abs(simdata[i] - c)) / 255
    from unnest('{1,2,3}'::integer[]) with ordinality tmp(c, i)
) as "similarity"
from "wallpapers" as "w"
order by "similarity" desc
limit 24
```

Comment: You are right, thi will not perform terribly well. PostgreSQL arrays are not made for performance, let alone parallel processing.